# jQuery returns the css for background-position in percents, when it was set in a string

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I am using this with a multiple background.

In my script, I set the values for background-position like so:

```
$this.css("background-position", "center " + value1 + "px,  center " + value2 + "px,  center" + value3 + "px,  center" + value4 );
```

`value1` to `value4` are integers which define where the images should be as the user scrolls the page.

What puzzles me is that, if I try to print these values in the console, they are returned in percentage values, with no "px" nor "center" indication either:

```
console.log( $this.css("background-position") )
```

returns something like this:

```
50% 100%, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, 50% 0%
```

Why `$this.css("background-position")` does not return the proper string that goes in the css? I've tried this with both Firefox and Chrome and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a few spaces after 'center' and a final 'px' string at the end.

give this a try.

```
$this.css("background-position", "center " + value1 + "px,  center " + value2 + "px,  center " + value3 + "px,  center " + value4 + 'px' );
```